# Translating "to be a thing" from English

Tags: traduction, oral

The casual phrase "to be a thing" in English is used to describe whether something exists, is commonly done, or is generally accepted as permissible behavior. Here are some examples:

> I wish there were a coffee machine that made my coffee automatically at my normal time every day. Is that a thing?

---

> Why are combined washer-dryers not a thing in the US?

---

> I tried to just buy one from them over the phone instead of going to the website, but apparently that's not a thing.

How would a French speaker express this concept?

Comment: I like the answers that have suggested multiple translations. That said, I think you're always safe (if not idiomatic) with "ça existe ?" P.S. I was just scoring the Ontario grade 10 literacy test, and I feel like "to be a thing" is definitely replacing "to exist" as standard English in that age group!

Answer (score 6):

One possible translation would be the use of "se faire" but it does not always apply and often you would use a specific verb.

> I wish there were a coffee machine that made my coffee automatically
> at my normal time every day. Is that a thing?
>
> J'aimerais une machine à café qui me fasse mon café à mon réveil tous les
> jours. Est-ce que ça se fait?

But you should say "Est-ce que ça existe?".

> Why are combined washer-dryers not a thing in the US?
>
> Pourquoi est-ce que les machines à laver sèche linge ne se font pas aux US?

But you should say "Pourquoi est-ce que les machines à laver sèche linge n'existent pas aux US?".

> I tried to just buy one from them over the phone instead of going to
> the website, but apparently that's not a thing.
>
> J'ai essayé de leur en acheter un au téléphone au lieu de passer par
> leur site internet mais apparemment, ça ne se fait pas.

But you should say "[...] mais apparemment c'est impossible.".

"Se faire" might convey a subtlety you may not want. The best example is the last sentence. "Ca ne se fait pas" may be understood as "It is rude to do so".

So I guess as @Flying_whale said, "there is no idiomatic way to translate to be a thing".

Answer (score 4):

"To be a thing" n'a pas de traduction exacte en français, en fonction du contexte on doit adapter la phrase:

> I wish there were a coffee machine that made my coffee automatically at my normal time every day. Is that a thing?
>
> J'aimerais une machine à café qui s'allume à mon réveil tout les jours. **Est-ce que ça existe**?

---

> Why are combined washer-dryers not a thing in the US?
>
> Pourquoi est-ce que les lave-linge/sèche-linge **ne sont pas vendus** aux US?

---

> I tried to just buy one from them over the phone instead of going to the website, but apparently that's not a thing.
>
> J'ai essayé d'en acheter un par téléphone au lieu d'autiliser leur site mais apparemment **ce n'est pas possible**.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use sentence formed with `exister`

for your first example `Is that a thing?` could be translated as `est-ce qu'une telle machine existe?`

your second sentence could be translated as `pourquoi les combinés machine à laver - sèche linge n'existent pas aux USA?`

Your last sentence could be translated as `J'ai essayer de leur en acheter une en téléphonant au lieu de passer par leur site internet, mais apparemment, c'est impossible`

To me, there is no idiomatic way to translate `to be a thing`

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account a quick googling:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be_a_thing

> (colloquial) to exist, or to be available, widespread, possible, or a
> common practice

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-a-thing

> to be an idea, product, or activity that is generally known or
> recognized

and the discussion here

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144171/the-idiom-be-a-thing

I would translate it by *exister, être répandu, connu, reconnu, etc.* depending on the context.

The other replies have already provided translations to your examples. As further examples:

> Apparently, eco-friendly underwear is a thing now.
>
> *Apparemment, les sous-vêtements écologiques sont répandus maintenant.*
>
> It is Valentine’s Eve. Is that even a thing?
>
> *C'est la veille de la Saint-Valentin. Est-ce que ça se fête, au-moins, ici ?*

Funilly enough Google uses...*être une chose* :-) !

Comment: Peut mieux faire... : un sous-vêtement, écologique ou pas, ne peut pas être « une pratique commune », « est-ce que c'est même connu » n'est pas idiomatique, et « drôlement » ne traduit pas *funnily* en début de phrase, on préférera « curieusement ».

Comment: Merci encore. J'ai modifiée ma réponse; s'elle n'est pas encore bonne je peux l'effacer:-)!